movement bug in 2D c game
For some reasons, the mySprite struct moves 2 times faster in the left direction (a key) rather than the right direction (d key), despite the magnitudes of delta_time and speed_x being exactly the same when either of the keys is pressed. Having ran the code, the logs tell me for a key: -2 and for for d key: 1. How is this possible?
typedef struct
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int x, y;
    pixel *pixels;
    bool *mask;
} sprite_t;

sprite_t mySprite;

void update()
{
    // Clear the surface
    SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGBA(surface->format, 0, 0, 0, 255));

    Uint32 *framebuffer = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels;

    // Draws pixels to the frame buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < mySprite.height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mySprite.width; ++j)
        {
            int pixel_index = (i * mySprite.width + j);
            setPixel(framebuffer, mySprite.x + j, mySprite.y + i, rgbaToUint32(&mySprite.pixels[pixel_index]));
        }
    }

    // Reset speed before processing input
    speed_x = 0;
    speed_y = 0;

    if (key_state.w)
        speed_y = -(SPEED);

    if (key_state.s)
        speed_y = SPEED;

    if (key_state.a)
        speed_x = -(SPEED);

    if (key_state.d)
        speed_x = SPEED;


    // Halts execution of update until the frame rate reaches target time
    int time_to_wait = FRAME_TARGET_TIME - (SDL_GetTicks() - last_frame_time);

    if (time_to_wait > 0 && time_to_wait <= FRAME_TARGET_TIME)
       SDL_Delay(time_to_wait);

    // Finds difference between last and current frame and divides by 1000 to convert to sec
    float delta_time = 0.016f;

    last_frame_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    int old_pos = mySprite.x;

    // Update sprite position
    mySprite.x += speed_x * delta_time;
    mySprite.y += speed_y * delta_time;

    if (key_state.a)

    if (key_state.d)
        printf("for d key: %i \n", mySprite.x - old_pos);
}

Tried adding logs to isolate the problem.
They should print:
for a key: -1
for d key: 1

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@3CxEZiVlQ: How is this question similar to that one? Where is there any suggestion this problem involves floating point?

@EricPostpischil Look at the code carefully especially at the second half.

@3CxEZiVlQ: That is not an answer to the questions I asked.

@3CxEZiVlQ: As OP notes, speed_x is set to values of the same sign, opposite magnitude. Floating-point arithmetic is symmetric, so speed_x * delta_time will have values of the same sign, opposite magnitude. The fact mySprite.x - old_pos is being printed with %i suggests they have integer types, likely both int. Then mySprite.x += speed_x * delta_time; is adding a floating-point value to an integer and converting back to integer. For example, suppose mySprite.x starts at 10 and speed_x * delta_time is +1.5 or −1.5. Then the addition produces 11.5 or 8.5, respectively,…

Please convert this to a [mre].

… and then the conversion back to integer produces 11 or 8, yielding a net change of +1 or −2. Now, observe this happens even if there is no floating-point rounding error at all. speed_x * delta_time might be exactly 1.5, or some other value, with no rounding error, and the addition might be exact too. The problem occurs in the conversion to int and would not be a result of floating-point rounding. Then it is not a duplicate of that problem.

@EricPostpischil Yes, it answers the question in 4. Rounding Errors in Other Operations: Truncation and 5. Repeated Operations.

@3CxEZiVlQ: Neither of those answers the issues here. The truncation in 4. is about a rounding method used internally to floating-point operations. It produces a tiny error. The truncation that occurs in conversion to integer is different and is not the subject of 4. 5. is not relevant because it is about errors accumulating in repeated operations, which does not seem to be the case here as the relevant error apparently occurs in a single operation.

The core problem looks like you are using integer types for members x and y but are calculating values for them using floating-point arithmetic.
This demonstrates the fundamental problem:
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int Start = 10;
    float Delta = .016f;
    int Speed = 100;

    float FloatEndA = Start + Delta*Speed;
    float FloatEndB = Start - Delta*Speed;
    
    printf("Floating-point endpoints are %g and %g.\n", FloatEndA, FloatEndB);

    int IntEndA = FloatEndA;
    int IntEndB = FloatEndB;

    printf("Integer endpoints are %d and %d.\n", IntEndA, IntEndB);
}

The output of this is:

Floating-point endpoints are 11.6 and 8.4.
Integer endpoints are 11 and 8.

This shows that the floating-point calculations produce endpoints of (approximately) 11.6 and 8.4, which are +1.6 and −1.6 from the starting point. But this code, as your code appears to, then assigns these points to integer types. That assignment automatically converts, and the conversion truncates the values, producing 11 and 8, which are +1 and −2 from the starting point.
Generally, physical systems are better modeled with floating-point or sufficiently fine fixed-point than with integer arithmetic. Unless you have some reason to believe all the quantities calculated will have integer values, you should generally use floating-point arithmetic for the calculations and for storing the values.
This may produce non-integer values for the coordinates of points. To render them on a display addressed by integer coordinates, you would have to convert the point coordinates to integers. That is best done as part of rendering, where the coordinate value is temporarily converted to the integer where it will be drawn. The coordinate value is not updated to that integer; it is kept as a floating-point value. That allows you to have non-integer speeds and locations, which allows finely varying speeds and locations instead of discrete jumps.
If you do want to keep the coordinates as integer types, you need to design the calculations so they produce integer results.
